# Webpack bundling with unused exported modules

Tags: webpack, bundle, uglifyjs

I have used ES6 modules in my application and bundle it using webpack2. When I bundle my application with external dependency from node_modules, it shows the unused modules in unminified output. However when I am bundling minified file, the unused module also bundled.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    context: __dirname + '/',
    entry: { 'main': './src/main.js' },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/',
        filename: "webpack2-test-es6.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel' }
        ]
    },   
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,                     
            debug: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: true,
                dead_code: true,
                unused: true,
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            sourceMap: false                        
        })            
    ]
}
```

The bundling process shows some warnings like

```
Side effects in initialization of unused variable
......
......
```

These side effects modules are /* unused harmony namespace reexport */, but it also bundled in the minified output.